# Post request fires instantly when page loads

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ajax, nodemailer

I have a simple one page website, where i have an email contact-form. My goal is to send an email to my account, when user fills the form and submits it. However, it doesn't work, cause POST request fires immediately after the page load and my **app.js** can't process the sendMail function, cause all the parameters are undefined.

[image: console error text]

This is my Node js function in app.js to send email:

```
const app = require('express')();
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const path = require('path');
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const express = require('express');

async function mainMail(name, email, message) {
    const transporter = await nodemailer.createTransport({
        service: 'gmail',
        auth: {
            user: '*my_email*',
            pass: '*my_password*'
        }
    });

    const mailOption = {
        from: '*my email*',
        to: '*my second email*',
        subject: email,
        html: `You've got message from:
        email: ${email}
        name: ${name}
        message: ${message}`
    };

    try {
        await transporter.sendMail(mailOption);
        return Promise.resolve('Message sent successfully');
    } catch(error) {
        return Promise.reject(error);
    }
}

app.post('/', async(req, res, next) => {
    try {
        await mainMail(req.body.name, req.body.email, req.body.message);
        res.send('Message sent!');
    } catch(error) {
        console.log(error);
        res.send('Message not sent!');
    }
})

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`PORT -> ${PORT}`);
});
```

And here is HTML Form:

```
<form method="post" class="contacts-form" id="contacts-form">
            <div class="contacts-upper-inputs">
                <div class="input-container half-input">
                    <label for="name" class="primary-label">Name</label>
                    <input required name="name" id="name" class="primary-input"></input>
                </div>
                <div class="input-container half-input">
                    <label for="email" class="primary-label">Email</label>
                    <input required name="email" id="email" class="primary-input"></input>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="input-container">
                <label for="message-text" class="primary-label">Message</label>
                <textarea required name="message" name="" id="message" cols="30" rows="10" class="primary-input"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div style="display: flex; justify-content: center;">
                <button onclick="sendEmail(event)" class="btn-contact">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </form>
```

And here is Submit handler on Submit button in index.js:

```
function sendEmail(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const name = document.getElementById('name').value;
    const email = document.getElementById('email').value;
    const message = document.getElementById('message').value;

    $.post('/', 
        {
            name: name,
            email: email,
            message: message
        },
        function(data, status) {
            console.log('status -> ', status);
        });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your button's `onclick` attribute should be just `sendEmail`, not `sendEmail(event)`. Adding the paranthesis will call the function instead of assigning it.

Comment: On that note, you should use form's submit event instead of button clicks since users can use enter key on the input field to submit the form